# Insert a Label in the empty groups of the CollectionView

Tags: xamarin.forms

Inside a `CollectionView` I have various groups, some with elements, others empty in which there is no element inside, but only the name of the group.
In empty groups is it possible to insert a `Label` instead of the `object` of my `class`?

UPDATE, MY CODE:

```
public class Diary
{    
     public DateTime Dt { get; set;}                          
     public string Nota { get; set; }
}

DiaryGroup hgroup = new DiaryGroup(NameGroup), new ObservableCollection<Diary>());

public ObservableCollection<DiaryGroup> TotalDiary = new ObservableCollection<DiaryGroup>();
TotalDiary.Add(hgroup);
```

In this case an empty group is inserted, with no elements inside it

Comment: include a placeholder object in the empty groups

Comment: I haven't found anything about placeholder objects, how can I implement them?

Comment: I can't give you any specific guidance because you haven't included any specific detail about what you're doing.  Generally speaking you just create an instance of your model and insert it into any empty groups

Comment: I have updated the code, can you help me? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try the code below. The `D` is the empty group.

Xaml:

```
<CollectionView IsGrouped="true" ItemsSource="{Binding Diarys}">
    <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label
                BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                FontSize="Large"
                Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding Dt}" />
                <Label
                    FontAttributes="Italic"
                    Text="{Binding Nota}"
                    VerticalOptions="End" />
            </StackLayout>


        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Code behind：

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public List<DiaryGroup> Diarys { get; private set; } = new List<DiaryGroup>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Diarys.Add(new DiaryGroup("A", new List<Diary>
        {
            new Diary { Dt = new DateTime(2020, 01, 24), Nota = "Nota_A" },
            new Diary { Dt = new DateTime(2020, 01, 25), Nota = "Nota_A" },
            new Diary { Dt = new DateTime(2020, 01, 26), Nota = "Nota_A" },
            new Diary { Dt = new DateTime(2020, 01, 27), Nota = "Nota_A" },

        }));

        Diarys.Add(new DiaryGroup("B", new List<Diary>
        {
            new Diary { Dt = new DateTime(2020, 02, 24), Nota = "Nota_B" },
            new Diary { Dt = new DateTime(2020, 02, 25), Nota = "Nota_B" },
            new Diary { Dt = new DateTime(2020, 02, 26), Nota = "Nota_B" },
            new Diary { Dt = new DateTime(2020, 02, 27), Nota = "Nota_B" },

        }));
        Diarys.Add(new DiaryGroup("C", new List<Diary>
        {
            new Diary { Dt = new DateTime(2020, 03, 24), Nota = "Nota_C" },
            new Diary { Dt = new DateTime(2020, 03, 25), Nota = "Nota_C" },
            new Diary { Dt = new DateTime(2020, 03, 26), Nota = "Nota_C" },
            new Diary { Dt = new DateTime(2020, 03, 27), Nota = "Nota_C" },

        }));
        Diarys.Add(new DiaryGroup("D", new List<Diary>
        {
            

        }));

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
}
public class Diary
{
    public DateTime Dt { get; set; }
    public string Nota { get; set; }
}
public class DiaryGroup : List<Diary>
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public DiaryGroup(string name, List<Diary> diary) : base(diary)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]